# How to configure routes.rb on bluehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, shared-hosting

I setted my RoR app to run on bluehost. The Rails main page is already showing, however I can't show my app's main page. I tried to configure the routes.rb file, but it's not working. What should I try to make this work?

This is what I tried so far:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
  root 'todos#index'
  get 'todos/index'
  post 'todos/index'
  map.root :controller=>’todos’, :action=>’index’
```

In my 'local' app, I only used the root, get and post line. The last line "map.root..." I got from this tutorial: [Setting up Ruby on Rails at Bluehost](http://www.esustain.com/blog/open_source_technologies/ruby_on_rails/setting-up-ruby-on-rails-at-bluehost/comment-page-2/).

Comment: Can you see your todos at `http://bluehost.address.whatever/todos`?

Comment: I can't. The page doesn't load

Comment: I am giving up pulling the information from you. _After all, what do you see if the page is not loaded_? An error message? 404? Many pink fairies dancing around the unicorn video?

Answer (score 1):

You are ending the routes block after  resources :todos. Therefor the rest of the routes declared are ignored including your 'root_path'

Try:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos
  root 'todos#index'
  get 'todos/index'
  post 'todos/index'
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. I'm still stuck on Welcome aboard ruby page